# Problems placing "driver.find_element_by_css_selector" in an if condition with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I'm trying to use a function from the webdriver library in an if condition, but this condition is situational, that is, it doesn't always happen.
Obviously it gives me an error because the times that the condition is not true, the function "driver.find_element_by_css_selector()" does not find the element. Is there a way to do it so that my code doesn't crash?

```
if driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#react-root > div > div > section > main > div > div > div > div > a").text() == 'Volver a Instagram.':
        return 0
    else:
        if(p == 1):
            elementName1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tWeCl")
            src_url = elementName1[0].get_attribute("src")
        if(p == 2):
            elementName2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tWeCl")
            src_url = elementName2[0].get_attribute("src")
```

Comment: .text, not text()

Comment: You can put that block of code in `try, except` block.

Answer (score 1):

You can change to find multiple elements `find_elements_by_css_selector`, it will return a list

-if list size = 0 --> no element

-if list size > 0 --> find element(s) match locator

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#react-root > div > div > section > main > div > div > div > div > a").text() == 'Volver a Instagram.'

if len(elements) == 0:
    # action when doesn't find any elements
else:
    if elements[0].text == "Volver a Instagram.":
        the rest...
```

Comment: My problem is in the condition of the first if, what is inside does not matter much because the code is not crashed by the inner ifs

Comment: Yes, I understand, my suggestion is change from `find_element` to `find_elements`.